# Improper conversion from jsf <h:commandButton> tag to html<input> tag

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2

I have a problem with `<h:commandButton/>` tag.if i see the converted HTML code by using browser inspect element the input element tag not closing.

**Original Output**

//JSF

```
<h:commandButton value="reset" type="reset" />
```

//HTML output

```
<input type="reset" name="xxx" value="reset" />
```

**Expected Output:**

//JSF

`<h:commandButton value="reset" type="reset"/>`

//HTML output

```
<input type="reset" name="xxx" value="reset">(Not closing i have seen by inspect element)
```

Why it is happening,can anyone get help out of it?

Comment: Why would you want it to render unclosed? And how is this even possible? The page should throw an `javax.servlet.ServletException` (Error Parsing /thePage.xhtml: Error Traced[line: xx] The element type "h:commandButton" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</h:commandButton>".)

Comment: It is conflict between your text and code. Text `the input element tag not closing`, code `<input type="reset" name="xxx" value="reset" />`.

Comment: Sorry to all please see the code once again.i want to see original output by inspect element but i am getting expected output

Comment: Why are you inspecting the browser-populated HTML DOM instead of looking at the JSF-generated HTML source? Rightclick in browser and do *View Source*. **That** is exactly what JSF has generated.

Comment: Wow !!!! Great BalusC